# Nifi:Writing new Processors

Tags: xpath, apache-nifi

I want  to make new  processor  which  will be the reunion of  GetFile and EvaluateXpath there are  several subject i am interested in:

1. How can i shrink my nar  file  now  it  is  more than  20kb and  my nifi can't  run  it?
2. I want to  get File  from folder read  it's data and  put it as an atribute inside new  flowfile,then  rolling back  config xml to  it's  original  folder  , how can i roll  my  config  file  back  to  folder  b code?
3. Here is  simple  code i use  for getting attributes  from xml  config  file :

   ```
   XPathExpression start = xpath.compile("//*[local-name()='start']");
                   XPathExpression startDate = xpath.compile("//*[local-name()='startDate']");
                   XPathExpression endDate = xpath.compile("//*[local-name()='endDate']");
                   XPathExpression runAs = xpath.compile("//*[local-name()='run']");
                   XPathExpression patch = xpath.compile("//*[local-name()='patch Information']");
   Object resultStart = start.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.STRING);
                   NodeList nodes = (NodeList) resultStart;
                   flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "start", String.valueOf(nodes.item(nodes.getLength()-1)));
   ```

   Map attributes = getAttributesFromFile(filePath);
               if (attributes.size() > 0) {
                   flowFile = session.putAllAttributes(flowFile, attributes);
               }

but  it does't work  properly, what should i change?

Answer (score 1):

As answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46531303/70465), I don't believe this use case requires custom processor development. Use `GetHDFS` with the *Keep source file*: `true` setting to maintain the file in the original location, and use `ExecuteXPath` with the various XPath values to extract data from the content into flowfile attributes. You can also use the combination of `ListHDFS` and `FetchHDFS` to keep the XML file in HDFS because NiFi will maintain state about which files it has seen.