# Nifi:How to make appropriate logic for Custom nifi procesessors

Tags: apache-nifi

I want to make custom nifi processors and here are several subjects i am interested in:

1.I want to get xml file from processor than parse it extract text values and put them as attribute for newle created flowfile but i want to update(i mean set new value to one of this tag value) and roll it back to folder,how can i roll back this flowfile?

2. if i want this file to be used by several processor should i use filec lock or when getting flowfile make keep source file false, which one is best practice?
   now i want OnTrigger Code like this:

   ```
       final List<File> files = new ArrayList<>(batchSize);
       queueLock.lock();
       try {
           fileQueue.drainTo(files, batchSize);
           if (files.isEmpty()) {
               return;
           } else {
               inProcess.addAll(files);
           }
       } finally {
           queueLock.unlock();
       }

       //make  xml parsing
       DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
       try {
           dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
       } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       Document doc = null;
       try {
           File f=  files.get(0);
           doc = dBuilder.parse(f);
       } catch (SAXException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("localAttributes");
       for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

           Node nNode = nList.item(temp);


           if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

               Element eElement = (Element) nNode;


               start = eElement.getElementsByTagName("start").item(0).getTextContent();
               startDate = eElement.getElementsByTagName("startDate").item(0).getTextContent();
               endDate = eElement.getElementsByTagName("endDate").item(0).getTextContent();
               patch = eElement.getElementsByTagName("patch").item(0).getTextContent();
               runAs = eElement.getElementsByTagName("runAs").item(0).getTextContent();

           }
       }

       final ListIterator<File> itr = files.listIterator();

       FlowFile flowFile = null;
       try {
           final Path directoryPath = directory.toPath();
           while (itr.hasNext()) {
               final File file = itr.next();
               final Path filePath = file.toPath();
               final Path relativePath = directoryPath.relativize(filePath.getParent());
               String relativePathString = relativePath.toString() + "/";
               if (relativePathString.isEmpty()) {
                   relativePathString = "./";
               }
               final Path absPath = filePath.toAbsolutePath();
               final String absPathString = absPath.getParent().toString() + "/";

               flowFile = session.create();
               final long importStart = System.nanoTime();
               flowFile = session.importFrom(filePath, keepingSourceFile, flowFile);
               final long importNanos = System.nanoTime() - importStart;
               final long importMillis = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(importNanos, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);

               flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, CoreAttributes.FILENAME.key(), file.getName());
               flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, CoreAttributes.PATH.key(), relativePathString);
               flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, CoreAttributes.ABSOLUTE_PATH.key(), absPathString)

               Map<String, String> attributes = getAttributesFromFile(filePath);
               if (attributes.size() > 0) {
                   flowFile = session.putAllAttributes(flowFile, attributes);
               }

               FlowFile flowFile1= session.create();
               flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, CoreAttributes.FILENAME.key(), file.getName());
               flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, CoreAttributes.PATH.key(), relativePathString);
               flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, CoreAttributes.ABSOLUTE_PATH.key(), absPathString);
               flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "start", start);
               flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "startDate", startDate);
               flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "endDate", endDate);
               flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "runAs", runAs);
               flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "patch", patch);

               session.getProvenanceReporter().receive(flowFile, file.toURI().toString(), importMillis);
               session.transfer(flowFile1, REL_SUCCESS);

               FlowFile flowFile3=session.create();
               flowFile3=session.importFrom(filePath, keepingSourceFile, flowFile);

               NodeList run = doc.getElementsByTagName("runAs");
               run.item(0).setNodeValue("false");
                session.transfer(flowFile3,REL_ROLLBACK);
               session.remove(flowFile);
   ```

Answer (score 3):

I have seen very similar questions posted here in recent days and have responded to both ["Nifi:Writing new Processors"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46531392/70465) and ["Nifi: how to write Custom processor"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46531303/70465).

I fully support learning how to do custom processor development in Apache NiFi, but this use case does not make sense to me. Retrieving a file from the file system (HDFS or otherwise) is an atomic unit of work which should not be combined with XML parsing. Combine a `GetFile` processor (or `ListFile`/`FetchFile` pair) with `EvaluateXPath` processor to perform this logic. The source file will remain in the original file system location, and you will get much more control and visibility into your flow, not to mention more robust performance and maintainability. If you need it to be used by many flows, you can export this segment as a template, or feed it input from other processors to determine which files to fetch and output to a `RouteOnAttribute` processor to direct the result to various consumers by `filename` or other such attributes.

If you are interested in custom processor development, the [Developer Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html) and [Contributor Guide](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NIFI/Contributor+Guide) both provide excellent reference information, and [Bryan Bende's blog](https://bryanbende.com/development/2015/02/04/custom-processors-for-apache-nifi) provides a good walkthrough.